# How to get USB drive serial number or meta data using java code

Tags: java, usb

I have prepared one desktop application in java. And I want to protect it by Pendrive or any other usb drive. But I dont know how to read pendrive or usb drive using java code, so that I can restrict the application.

Plese help me how to do this? Or any other idea regarding this?

Thanks..:)

Comment: I would be surprised if this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Like the person above me said, you can list the roots of your USB directory. After you list the roots, you can find the USB drive manually then write the File object from your USB drive to a File using FileOutputStreams and then just compare that File object later to your drive. Or you can make a unique file name in your USB drive and use

```
File[] roots = File.listRoots();for(int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++){
File[] filesInRoot = File.listRoots()[i].listFiles();
for(int j = 0; j < filesInRoot.length; j++){
    if(filesInRoot[j].getName().equals(yourUniqueFileName))
        executeYourCode();

    }
}
```

Ask any questions if you need it! This is a very interesting problem so if you need help with the code, chat me!

Comment: Thaks..:) I will try this....but still my doubt is this unique file can be copied to other pendrive also, and that pendrive can be used for the apps. In this way it will not be protected based on single pendrive only.

Comment: You just need to make sure that nobody can get the pendrive!

Comment: To find the USB device, have a look to [`getSystemTypeDescription()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemTypeDescription%28java.io.File%29). It returns something like "Removable device".

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code for return the USB or disk drive.

```
public String HDD_SerialNo(){
    StringBuffer HDD_Serial=new StringBuffer();
    String HDD_Number;
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process=rt.exec(new String[]{"CMD", "/C", "WMIC diskdrive get serialnumber"});
        String s = null;
        //Reading sucessful output of the command
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            HDD_Serial.append(s);
        }
        // Reading error if any
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.print(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is nice, and the first example online I've found of obtaining any information from an attached USB.  Do you know how to get any hardware specific information from the USB?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Jinput](http://java.net/projects/jinput/). If it is not powerful enough for you, try [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/).

P.S.: I would like to add, that this kind of protection can be easily cracked. So why you want to punish your customers for not pirating?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Java SE you can only refer to drives on Windows by using the [`File.listRoots()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29), which will just return a list like `{"C:\", "D:\", "E:\"}`, and of course, the USB drive could be mounted on (essentially) any drive letter.

If you want to restrict the application from running when the USB drive is not mounted then perhaps you could look for a known file (with special contents) on the the drive by searching for it under each of the file roots.

Comment: Thanks for reply..:) But using File.listRoots() how I can identify whether it is particular USB drive attached or not? Actully I have a tool using that I can get the pendrive serial number, and I want make it compared that serial number using java code in my application. Please help how it can be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [jusb](http://www.steelbrothers.ch/jusb/) api for that.

```
package usb.main;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import usb.core.Bus;
import usb.core.Configuration;
import usb.core.Endpoint;
import usb.core.Host;
import usb.core.HostFactory;
import usb.core.Interface;
import usb.windows.DeviceImpl;



public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Host host = HostFactory.getHost();

        Bus[] bus = host.getBusses();

        SearchUSBDevices(bus);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

private static void SearchUSBDevices(Bus[] bus) {
    boolean FOUND_FLAG = false;
    try {
        DeviceImpl dev;
        for (int k = 0; k < bus.length; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                dev = (DeviceImpl) bus[k].getDevice(i);
                if (dev != null) {
                    // System.out.println(dev.getString(1, 1));
                    if (dev.getAddress() >= 1) {
                        if (dev.getNumPorts() > 0)
                            ;
                        else {
                            // System.out.println("Device Name :"+dev.getFriendlyDeviceName());
                            if (dev.getFriendlyDeviceName()
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                            "USB Mass Storage Device")) {

                                FOUND_FLAG = true;

                                // // START
                                //
                                if (dev != null) {
                                    // Obtain the current Configuration of
                                    // the device and the number of
                                    // Interfaces available under the
                                    // current Configuration.
                                    Configuration config = dev
                                            .getConfiguration();
                                    int total_interface = config
                                            .getNumInterfaces();

                                    // Traverse through the Interfaces
                                    for (int k1 = 0; k1 < total_interface; k1++) {
                                        // Access the currently Interface
                                        // and obtain the number of
                                        // endpoints available on the
                                        // Interface.
                                        Interface itf = config
                                                .getInterface(k1, 0);
                                        int total_ep = itf
                                                .getNumEndpoints();
                                        System.out.println(total_ep);
                                        // Traverse through all the
                                        // endpoints.
                                        for (int l = 0; l < total_ep - 1; l++) {
                                            // Access the endpoint, and
                                            // obtain its I/O type.
                                            Endpoint ep = itf
                                                    .getEndpoint(l);
                                            String io_type = ep.getType();
                                            System.out.println(io_type);
                                            boolean input = ep.isInput();
                                            System.out.println(input);

                                            // If the endpoint is an input
                                            // endpoint, obtain its
                                            // InputStream and read in data.
                                            if (input) {
                                                InputStream in;
                                                in = ep.getInputStream();
                                                // Read in data here
                                                /*
                                                 * byte[] b = new byte[100];
                                                 * in.read(b);
                                                 */
                                                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
                                                        new InputStreamReader(
                                                                in));
                                                String line;

                                                /*
                                                 * while ((line =
                                                 * bReader.read
                                                 * (cbuf))!=null){
                                                 * System.out
                                                 * .println(line); }
                                                 */
                                                in.close();
                                            }
                                            // If the Endpoint is and output
                                            // Endpoint, obtain its
                                            // OutputStream and write out
                                            // data.
                                            else {
                                                OutputStream out;
                                                out = ep.getOutputStream();
                                                // Write out data here.
                                                out.close();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // END
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (FOUND_FLAG)
            System.out.println("Pendrive Found..");
        else
            System.out.println("Pendrive Not Found ...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}